# Is it possible to consume by several consumers from the same queue in JMS?

Tags: java, jms, messaging

I am learning JMS and I know that there 2 types of communication:
1. queues
2  topics

I understand topics but I could not understand is it possible to read from same queue by 2 different consumers.

I ask about it because I know it is possible in amqp.

lets we have queue like this

```
tail -> |5|4|3|2|1|-> head
```

and following action order:

1. consumer_1 read  and got 1
2. consumer_2 read  and got 2
3. consumer_1 read  and got 3
4. consumer_2 read  and got 4
5. consumer_2 read  and got 5

Is it possible or it is contradicts the point-to-point approach?

Comment: Firstly it depends on the implementation, so please go through the docs, which implementation you are using ?, well, it should be possible to configure in such a way.

Comment: @Raghuveer I just try to learn.At the moment I am reading theory

Comment: Yes, it's possible (and very often used, simply to consume messages in multiple threads, for example)

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the semantic you want to apply on your Q: strict FIFO or parallel processing..

Implementation of the semantic (Q + Consumers + parallel architecture  etc.) is  product/architecture dependent (ie cluster or not, multi threads etc.).

The semantic of a Q containing messages for updating an inventory is probably FIFO and must be processed in strict order, a queue with messages of mails to be send to customers is probably parallel and can be processed in any order with possibly many concurrent consumers

Comment: Adding to this JMS also allows for hybrids of parallel processing and strict order. Using the JMSXGroupID and JMSXGroupSeq properties the producer can make sure a group/batch of messages will be processed by the same consumer (thread/process/node).